# Decouple logic from transformation when filtering records

Tags: haskell

Below is a simplified example of a problem I have with larger records and functions doing some data manipulation. In my actual code `name` is an accessor like:

`name = snd . fst . fst`

However I'm not content with readability as `name` is not the only one thing I want to check against. Is there a simpler, idiomatic way to decouple logic from field transformation based on this example?

```
> data Athlete = Athlete { name :: String } deriving Show

> let registered = map Athlete ["John", "Mike"]
> let input = map Athlete ["John", "Ann"]

> filter (not . (`elem` (map name registered)) . name) input
[Athlete {name = "Ann"}]
```

Part of the problem is that predicate does not only depend on the argument itself and does not necessarily check for equality of `Athlete`. Since I explicitly do not want test for equality, ideally, the logic part should remain unchanged if the `input` type changed to the following:

```
> data AthleteInput = AthleteInput { name :: String } deriving Show
```

Comment: I feel like there's an interesting question here, but quite what you're asking isn't clear to me.

Comment: Something like:  `let func f input registered = filter (not . (\`elem\` (map f registered)) . f) input`? Not 100% sure what's being asked.

Comment: I feel like you want structural records - the built-in record system will not help you here but there are plenty of libraries implementing records to choose from.

Comment: Consider this a novice question about structuring and efficiency of Haskell code. The "logic" is a simple set intersection. The mapping is creating temporary sets from database and user input. The hidden topic is related to having two types share the same (in terms of semantics) field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I propose something like this: we will use `Data.Map` to give two mappings that share a key space. Building these `Map`s will correspond to the "predicate" part; this will be cleanly separated from computing the "intersection" or other combining function. We start with the same setup as yours:

```
import Data.Map (Map)
import qualified Data.Map as M

data Athlete = Athlete { name :: String } deriving Show
registered = map Athlete ["John", "Mike"]
input = map Athlete ["John", "Ann"]
```

Now we will build our two maps. For exposition, I will name them; but in your code you may choose to inline their definitions to avoid having to choose a crappy name.

```
registeredMap :: Map String Athlete
registeredMap = M.fromList [(name athlete, athlete) | athlete <- registered]

inputMap :: Map String Athlete
inputMap = M.fromList [(name athlete, athlete) | athlete <- input]
```

I stress here that we have *happened* to use `name` as the selector for both cases here, and *happened* to use the same type `Athlete` as the value types for both maps, but neither of these is required for the next part -- just coincidence. The key non-coincidental bit as that the key spaces are the same, as otherwise intersection would not make sense. This addresses your design concern of later needing to change one accessor or the other, or change one underlying type or the other.

Now intersection is as simple as using the existing library function `intersection`.

```
registeredInputAthletes :: [Athlete]
registeredInputAthletes = M.elems (M.intersection registeredMap inputMap)
```

This has value `[Athlete { name = "John" }]`.

If it is a need, one could also use `intersectionWith` to combine the two contained values rather than keeping the one from the left-hand argument and ignoring the right-hand argument.

Comment: I didn't notice that `b` is unconstrained in: `intersection :: Ord k => Map k a -> Map k b -> Map k a`. It seems that `Map` in `Map k b` is an over-constrained parameter allowing for efficient computation with type-class uniqueness.